# How to turn off MoreShapes menu in Visio 2019 drawing control in .NET c#

Tags: c#-4.0, visio

I have used this below logic to hide More Shapes stencil in Visio 2019 visioControl.Document.Application.DoCmd((short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisUICmds.visCmdHideMoreShapes).

Instead of More Shapes, it is hiding Quick Shapes.
I am unable to hide More Shapes. I would require a c# code to implement this scenario.Could you please support me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have there C# IDE. I write VBA macro for close **Shapes Window**.
You must iterate all co-windows, if one of them have caption **Shapes** close it !

```
 Sub For_BHARGAVI()
 Dim AW As Window, cw As Window
 Set AW = ActiveWindow
 For Each cw In AW.Windows
 If cw.Type = 10 And cw.Caption = "Shapes" Then
 cw.Close
 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

**PS** Menu **MoreShapes** is always visible when **Shapes** window is open…